# how to add css nth child inside react const

Tags: reactjs

how to add css nth child inside react const. Right now it has it is in a css stylesheet but I want to include it inside js file. `<FaBeer>` is react icon.

react:

```
const defaultStyles = {
  color: "green"
}



const beerStyling = () => {

 return(
    <div>
      <span> <FaBeer /> </span>
      <span> <FaBeer /> </span>
      <span> <FaBeer /> </span>
    </div>
 )

}
```

css:

```
span:nth-child(-n+2){
  color: red;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can put all your css in a single file and then require the css file in your react code,just like:

```
require('./mystyle.css')
```